# strstr matching first occurrence in c

Tags: c, strstr

I was wondering how could I match the string `"Just"` in `str1` if `str1` contains the strings as:

```
"this is Just/1.1.249.4021 a test" 
// "Just" will always be the same
```

I'm trying to match it using `strstr` but so far it won't match because of the `/...`

Any suggestions on how to match it? Thanks

Comment: Does this actually compile? It seems like you have an invalid string literal there - `\2323` isn't a valid escape code AFAIK.

Comment: @Evgeny: \2323 is a valid octal escape \232 followed by digit 3.

Comment: Sorry, the string should be as: Just/1.1.249.4021

Comment: What do you mean by "Just/1.1.249.4021"?  Is this the needle or the haystack?  And are you looking for a case-insensitive string search?  If so, you need a non-standard function.

Comment: needle should be "Just" (case sensitive). haystack is the original string "this is Just/1.1.249.4021 a test"

Comment: OK - well then a trivial adaptation of the code shown in my answer will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me - what about you?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char haystack[] = "this is just\2323 a test";
    char needle[] = "just";
    char *loc = strstr(haystack, needle);
    if (loc == 0)
        printf("Did not find <<%s>> in <<%s>>\n", needle, haystack);
    else
        printf("Found <<%s>> in <<%s> at <<%s>>\n", needle, haystack, loc);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the string should be as: Just/1.1.249.4021

Comment: The C++ standard says that string literals are of type "array of const char", thus it is recommended to declare them as const char*

Comment: @rep_movsd: yes, but I'm not declaring any string literals.  I'm declaring two variable arrays with convenient initializers.  Granted, I could make them const; there is absolutely no obligation to do so, and I could modify the strings (carefully) if I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Something must be wrong with how you use strstr()
The following code works just fine...

```
const char *s = "this is just\2323 a test";
char *p = strstr(s, "just");
if(p)
    printf("Found 'just' at index %d\n", (int)(p - s));
```

Answer (score -1):

If the string is actually "Just/1.1.249.4021" then it would fail to find "just", because `strstr` is case-sensitive. If you need a case-insensitive version you have to write your own or [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=strstr+case+insensitive) for an existing implementation.